# What to do about being loaded with much more work than colleagues?

Tags: professionalism, workload

I work as a public school teacher. Starting this year, the principal started assigning staff to various committees. Each are responsible for different tasks, such as writing newsletters, organizing family nights, etc. Some committees might involve just 30-minutes of work per week, while others  are very involved and complex. Staff cannot work on these during class hours, as we're responsible for teaching during those hours, so often this is take-home work.

Most teachers were assigned to exactly one committee. I've been gradually added to TWELVE. Some were newly created, and the principal just decided I belong there. Others co-workers protested their work, and it was reassigned to me. In addition, though most committees should be a group effort, most people on my committees don't pull their weight. Many committees don't even have other members.

- From my observations, those close friends with the principal were assigned very light tasks.
- Others put up very loud protests, and were dropped from their responsibilities.
- Some have found various excuses for not doing the work -- ex. they have things at home they must take care of.
- Most just stay quiet, never do any work, and hope (it seems correctly) the principal will forget.

I've tried pushing back during the most recent additions to my assignments, with no luck. The principal even told me some new duties wouldn't be a big deal---when they were in fact the most time-consuming added duties yet!

How can I deal with this seriously unfair situation?

Comment: Are you in the USA? If so then you are almost certainly a union member and you can speak to your union representative about this.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is in Education - for every Committee, make a loud suggestion that the *only* solution involves the spending of Money....

Okay - Jokes aside - there's a magical word that you need to learn. Learning it will improve your Professional life. It is a powerful word and should be used only in the appropriate situation...

"No."

When the Principle asks you to do something and you are already at capacity - you need to say "No."

Be Polite, but be firm. If pressed - all you need to do is say something like:

"I'm currently at capacity with XY and Z, I cannot commit the extra time needed to be productive on this comittee"

Answer (score 4):

You wrote the answer already.

1. Become close friends with the principal
2. Put up a very loud protest.
3. Find excuses for not doing the work, e.g. have things to do at home
4. Stay quiet, never do any work, and hope he forgets.

If you think you can't do that, use up to 2 hours a week for these tasks, and see how far you get.

Comment: The caveat to this is that it doesn't mesh well with someone who has high personal integrity.